# PHP Laravel view json

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with showing json from controller to view.
If I return only json response I have.

```
{"result":true,"title":"Cable"}
```

As normal.

But when I try to implement it to blade it's not working. I'm doing it like this in controller.

```
$data1 = $getProduct->index();

        $data = array(
            'title'=> $data1['title'],
            'Description'=>'This is New Application',
            );
```

and this in view

```
{{ $title }}
```

and error like

```
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse as array
```

Comment: Can you show more of the controller?  What does `getIndex()` return? It looks like it returns a JsonResponse instead of just the JSON.

Comment: Yes this is return..... return response()->json([
            'result' => true,
            'title' => $title,
            'orders' => $orders,
           // 'description' => $description,
            'var' => $var,
            'images' => $images,
        ], 200);

Comment: There's your problem, you should not use `response()->json()` if you want to return a blade. instead do `return view('view_name', ['result' => true, ... ])`. Since you're calling that method from another method it seems like you're using controllers wrong and I can't advise how to fix it without more information. What does `$getProduct` contain? Is it another controller?

Comment: I'm returning informations from one controller to another. That's why I tried to return json, this return is ```$getProduct->index()``` , now when I show only getProduct I can see json response, when I decode it it's NULL, when I encode it I have return like ```{headers: {}, original: {"title":"Cable"}}```

Comment: when you do `response()->json()` you're not returning a JSON object, you're returning a Response object that contains JSON. Those are two very different things.

Comment: Is this resolved? Please mark the answer that helped as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a single function to return data for multiple endpoints (one json and one view). This is good except that shared function should return an array instead of a JsonResponse. The JsonResponse class isn't a JSON object, it is a Response object that has the data in addition to all the response data like headers, cookies, etc.

Update the `index()` to return an array. From your comments it sounds like this is contained in a controller, but it is used in a different controller. This should live in its own class that is then called from any controller that needs it.

```
public function index()
{
    // retrieve/generate data
    return [ 'result' => true, 'title' => $title, 'orders' => $orders ];
}
```

Then in your json route do:

```
public function jsonEndpoint()
{
    return response()->json($getProduct()->index());
}
```

Then in your blade route do:

```
public function bladeEndpoint()
{
    $data1 = $getProduct->index();

     $data = array(
         'title'=> $data1['title'],
         'Description'=>'This is New Application',
     );

     return view('view_name', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse` indicates that your returned data is not an array but an object.

Based on that, you should do something like this:

```php
$data1 = $getProduct->index();

// As $data1 is Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
// you need to get the data in object format (not array)

$data = array(
  'title'=> $data->title,
  'Description'=>'This is New Application',
);
```

That should do it.

**Note:** if `$data1` is null, then your json is bad formatted.

[See Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse official docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dd(your_object) or dump(your_object) to see exactly what's inside your object before sending it as on the response

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `json_decode()` to convert json object into a php array

```
$data = json_decode($data1);
echo $data->title; // Cable
```

Comment: When I do this it's null.

Comment: can you do a `print_r(getProduct->index());` and paste the result

Comment: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse Object ( [data:protected] => {"result":true,"title":"Cable"} ....

Comment: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object